# How to populate JList with certain words from txt file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jlist

I need help with `JList`.  Need to add a text file to a list but txt file is named `library.txt` with:

```
title1 author1 description1 publisher1
title2 author2 description2 publisher2
title3 author3 description3 publisher3
title4 author4 description4 publisher4
```

What program needs to do is to fill list **only** with titles from txt and when user select certain title from list the program needs to write the description to a `JTextArea`.

This is what I got so far.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Library extends JFrame {

    private JList lista;
    private JTextArea tekst;
    DefaultListModel model;

    public Library() {
        super("Biblioteka");
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        lista = new JList(model);
        add(lista);
        tekst = new JTextArea(20, 20);
        add(tekst);
        File fajl = new File("library.txt");
        BufferedReader ulaz = null;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fajl);
            ulaz = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String linija;
            try {
                while ((linija = ulaz.readLine()) != null) {
                    //lista.add(linija);
                    //System.out.println(linija);
                    String[] reci = linija.split("\t");
                    String naslovi = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < reci.length; i++) {
                        naslovi = reci[0];
                    }
                    int pos = lista.getModel().getSize();
                    model.addElement(naslovi.toString());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Library l = new Library();
        l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        l.setSize(300, 430);
        l.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"This is what I got so far."*  Please use a logical & consistent indent for code blocks.  That code reads like it was written by your dog.  I love dogs, but would not debug their code. 2) Please examine the preview of your post carefully before posting.  As it is I had to tidy that up, & have better things to be doing. 3) Create a POJO to represent the `Book` and put `Book` instances in the list.  Use a renderer to make them appear as needed.  When selected, use the object to get the detail to show in the rest of the GUI.  4) Doing 3. would make the question redundant.

Comment: 5) Swing code should be executed on the EDT 6) And what exactly is your question. You show us a work-in-progress but forget to mention where you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew mentioned in his comments use a POJO (plain old java object) like

```
class Book {
    String title;
    String author;
    String description:
    /* other fields*/
}
```

Then rewrite your loop similar to

```
while ((linija = ulaz.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] reci = linija.split("\t");

    for (int i = 0; i < reci.length; i++) {
         Book book = new Book();
         book.title = reci[0];
         book.description = reci[2];
         /* other stuff here */
         model.addElement(book);
     }
}
```

Use then a `ListCellRenderer` to display only the title in the `List` and a `ListSelectionListener` to listen and update the text area accordingly